# Flow: react-router. Required module not found

Tags: react-router, flowtype

Why is `flow` throwing this error? My app works fine, i.e. `react-router` npm module is working.

```
$ flow
Launching Flow server for /Users/carlf/Documents/dev/reactjs/FlyTweet
Spawned flow server (child pid=21264)
Logs will go to /private/tmp/flow/zSUserszScarlfzSDocumentszSdevzSreactjszSFlyTweet.log
app.js:6
  6: import { Router, Route, Link, hashHistory, IndexRoute } from 'react-router';
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ react-router. Required module not found
```

Comment: I'm having this same issue actually.

Comment: It's only complaining about the `react-router` npm module, not an issue with `import from` a local file. I haven't tried importing any other npm modules except `react` stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Most npm modules don't have proper flow definitions, so you will need to add one via a flow interfaces.

For example you can do the following:

```
$ npm install iflow-react-router --save-dev
```

Then in your flowconfig

```
[libs]
./node_modules/iflow-react-router/index.js.flow
```

Then it flow will be able to consume the flow definition from react-router.

---

You can find iflow-react-router here https://github.com/marudor/flowInterfaces/tree/master/packages

FYI, another project is emerging where you can find flow interfaces https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed

Comment: Thanks. And, Wow, that's a PITA. `iflow-react-router` is missing `hashHistory` from latest version of `react-router`. Is there any other way to supress these errors i.e. in `.flowconfig`?

Answer (score 2):

https://dsslimshaddy.github.io/flowignore/.

Just write the packages you need to import and copy the first regex in the [ignore] of flowconfig file.

It basically says that ignore all node modules except the ones you specify.